# create a double column graph in fpdf php

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm creating a graph in fpdf and I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925279/how-to-create-double-bar-diagram-using-fpdf-php) and it is exactly the same as what I need but when I copied it on my **report-weekly.php** file it doesn't work and gave me an error message of

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\qtqt\asd\report-weekly.php on line 112
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\qtqt\asd\report-weekly.php on line 112
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\qtqt\asd\report-weekly.php on line 112
> FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

this is the code I copied

```
<?php

require('diag/sector.php');

class PDF_Diag extends PDF_Sector {
    var $legends;
    var $wLegend;
    var $sum;
    var $NbVal;


    function ColumnChart($w, $h, $data, $format, $color=null, $maxVal=0, $nbDiv=4)
    {

        // RGB for color 0
        $colors[0][0] = 155;
        $colors[0][1] = 75;
        $colors[0][2] = 155;

        // RGB for color 1
        $colors[1][0] = 0;
        $colors[1][1] = 155;
        $colors[1][2] = 0;

        // RGB for color 2
        $colors[2][0] = 75;
        $colors[2][1] = 155;
        $colors[2][2] = 255;

        // RGB for color 3
        $colors[3][0] = 75;
        $colors[3][1] = 0;
        $colors[3][2] = 155;

        $this->SetFont('Courier', '', 10);
        $this->SetLegends($data,$format);

        // Starting corner (current page position where the chart has been inserted)
        $XPage = $this->GetX();
        $YPage = $this->GetY();
        $margin = 2; 

        // Y position of the chart
        $YDiag = $YPage + $margin;

        // chart HEIGHT
        $hDiag = floor($h - $margin * 2);

        // X position of the chart
        $XDiag = $XPage + $margin;

        // chart LENGHT
        $lDiag = floor($w - $margin * 3 - $this->wLegend);

        if($color == null)
            $color=array(155,155,155);
        if ($maxVal == 0) 
        {
            foreach($data as $val)
            {
                if(max($val) > $maxVal)
                {
                    $maxVal = max($val);
                }
            }
        }

        // define the distance between the visual reference lines (the lines which cross the chart's internal area and serve as visual reference for the column's heights)
        $valIndRepere = ceil($maxVal / $nbDiv);

        // adjust the maximum value to be plotted (recalculate through the newly calculated distance between the visual reference lines)
        $maxVal = $valIndRepere * $nbDiv;

        // define the distance between the visual reference lines (in milimeters)
        $hRepere = floor($hDiag / $nbDiv);

        // adjust the chart HEIGHT
        $hDiag = $hRepere * $nbDiv;

        // determine the height unit (milimiters/data unit)
        $unit = $hDiag / $maxVal;

        // determine the bar's thickness
        $lBar = floor($lDiag / ($this->NbVal + 1));
        $lDiag = $lBar * ($this->NbVal + 1);
        $eColumn = floor($lBar * 80 / 100);

        // draw the chart border
        $this->SetLineWidth(0.2);
        $this->Rect($XDiag, $YDiag, $lDiag, $hDiag);

        $this->SetFont('Courier', '', 10);
        $this->SetFillColor($color[0],$color[1],$color[2]);
        $i=0;
        foreach($data as $val) 
        {
            //Column
            $yval = $YDiag + $hDiag;
            $xval = $XDiag + ($i + 1) * $lBar - $eColumn/2;
            $lval = floor($eColumn/(count($val)));
            $j=0;
            foreach($val as $v)
            {
                $hval = (int)($v * $unit);
                $this->SetFillColor($colors[$j][0], $colors[$j][1], $colors[$j][2]);
                $this->Rect($xval+($lval*$j), $yval, $lval, -$hval, 'DF');
                $j++;
            }

            //Legend
            $this->SetXY($xval, $yval + $margin);
            $this->Cell($lval, 5, $this->legends[$i],0,0,'C');
            $i++;
        }

        //Scales
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $nbDiv; $i++) 
        {
            $ypos = $YDiag + $hRepere * $i;
            $this->Line($XDiag, $ypos, $XDiag + $lDiag, $ypos);
            $val = ($nbDiv - $i) * $valIndRepere;
            $ypos = $YDiag + $hRepere * $i;
            $xpos = $XDiag - $margin - $this->GetStringWidth($val);
            $this->Text($xpos, $ypos, $val);
        }
    }

    function SetLegends($data, $format)
    {
        $this->legends=array();
        $this->wLegend=0;
        $this->NbVal=count($data);
    }
}


$pdf = new PDF_Diag();
$pdf->AddPage();


$data[0] = array(470, 490, 90);
$data[1] = array(450, 530, 110);
$data[2] = array(420, 580, 100);


// Column chart
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'BIU', 12);
$pdf->Cell(210, 5, 'Chart Title', 0, 1, 'C');
$pdf->Ln(8);
$valX = $pdf->GetX();
$valY = $pdf->GetY();
$pdf->ColumnChart(110, 100, $data, null, array(255,175,100));
//$pdf->SetXY($valX, $valY);

$pdf->Output();


?>
```

Comment: could you share the content of the file `report-weekly.php` as well?

Comment: it is the same as the one on the link, I literally just copied and pasted it

Comment: it has the same require 'diag/sector.php' file location

Comment: Post your code, do not refer to outside resources

Comment: look in line 112, your code is looking for an array of something with key 0,1 and 2, and you did not give it an array of something with keys 0, 1 and 2

Comment: $this->legends[$i] in line 112 of the code you copied suggests you add some legends

Comment: I updated the question @Lelio Faieta. please have a look